# ffmpeg: Very High Frame Rate Values with -r option

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Please don't mark this as a duplicate just because it mentions "ffmpeg frame rate".  My question is not just a simple "How do I set the frame rate?"

I have set the output framerate of my video to a standard 30fps using the `-r` option, however, FFMPEG's output values are closer to 250 for some reason.

Here's my syntax: `ffmpeg.exe -y -i "C:\some\long\path.mp4" -f mp4 -r "30" -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -filter:v scale=320:240 -b:v 1000k  -aspect 16:9 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -b:v 1250k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -bf 3 -coder 1 -me_method umh -me_range 16 -subq 7 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8+partb8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 112k -ar 48000 -ac 2  "C:\some\long\path-output.mp4"`

Note the `-r "30"` on the first line.

Thanks,

HewwoCraziness

Comment: 1. This isn't a programming question so it is off-topic here: it would be on-topic at [su] or video.stackexchange.com 2. You should always show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command. 3. Why are you declaring so many options after setting your preset? The preset will handle most of those options. 4. Why are you assuming the frame rate is 250? I think you're confusing it with the GOP size that you set with `-g 250`.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I found some ffmpeg questions and assumed this would be a good place.  2. Sorry again.  3. I use WinFF so I think it defaults to using all parameters, even if they're not modified.  4. In my output, it showed `fps=250` or above, so I assumed that was frames per second.

Comment: Edit:  I don't think I'm confusing it with anything.  On another series of videos, I'm getting a framerate of around 65 with the same options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the current rate of the encoding process, not the frame rate of the output file.

Comment: Oops!  That makes more sense anyway.  Thanks!